# Servlet mapping with multiple matches

Tags: servlets, mapping, pattern-matching, multiple-matches

I have a question according the mapping behaviour.

If there are these mappings given:

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name> ServletA </servlet-name>
   <url-pattern> *.xml </url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name> ServletB </servlet-name>
   <url-pattern> /result/* </url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And there is this HTTP-Request:

```
/result/example.xml
```

Which servlet would be mapped and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your `<servlet-mapping>` configuration, the request for `/result/example.xml` would be handled by `ServletB` because a path match always trumps an extension match.

This is so because an extension match is considered to be a looser (not loser, though that works too :) constraint as it works site-wide when compared to a path match which targets a specific directory and its descendents and is hence more specific in nature.

The matching priority goes like this:

1. Exact path match
2. Wildcard path match (a longer match will trump a shorter one)
3. Extension match
4. Default servlet (configured with just `/` to handle all 404s)